# Spring JPA Test - InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException

Tags: spring, jpa

I have an entity

```
    @Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "VGI_TRADESDBO.TRADELOG")
public class TradeLog {
    @Id
    @Column(name="TRADE_ID")
        private Long tradeId;
…
```

And a Repository

```
public interface TradeLogRepository extends JpaRepository<TradeLog, Long>{
```

And a schema.sql file

```
CREATE SCHEMA "VGI_TRADESDBO"


CREATE TABLE "VGI_TRADESDBO"."TRADELOG" 
   (    "TRADE_ID" NUMBER(38,0),
```

Finally I have a cucumber step def that injects that Repository and tries to save to it

```
    @DataJpaTest
    @Sql({"schema.sql"})
    public class TradesToTsoStep{
@Inject TradeLogRepository tradeLogRepo;
```

and yet I get a `Column "TRADELOG0_.TRADE_ID" not found;`

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement
```

Has anyone run into this? And why is it sticking the 0_ into the column name?

Comment: `TRADELOG0_` is just the alias for the table used in the generated SQL. It might be the case that `@Sql` doesn't get picked up for some reason. Does it work when you move `schema.sql` to `src/test/resources` and drop `@Sql`? You can also try enabling schema auto-generation by setting `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update`, `create`, or `create-drop`

Comment: Should I be setting that in my application.properties, or in a test-only equivalent properties file? And no dropping @Sql doesn't make a difference

Comment: You can do it in `application.yml` under `src/test/resources` if you don't want it to affect production

Comment: Also, this might be irrelevant, but does changing the table annotation to  `@Table(name = "TRADELOG", schema = "VGI_TRADESDBO")` help? It might be that your schema SQL works just fine, but the generated SQL is somehow misformatted. You should be able to verify that by setting `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql` to `true` and examining the query from the logs

Comment: I think my issue is more mundane than all this. NUMBER is not a valid H2 data type, among possibly other sql issues. I removed the quotes and put a semicolon after the schema creation line and suddenly I got sql errors. Super weird, but it works now.